# 3D holograms like Miku Hatsune? How do you make such things?

Tags: optics, hologram

I am making a speech about [Miku Hatsune 3D hologram](http://www.google.com/search?q=miku+hatsune+3d+hologram), and I would like to know how they are made! I love Miku and Len...(drools) please help by explaining!

Comment: Mentioned in the [comments to an earlier question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/3d-holograms-how-are-they-created#comment54264_23497).